# Super capacitors as DC blockers

Tags: capacitor

Can two super capacitors connected in series back to back be used as DC blockers when in series with an AC supply and load, regular polarized capacitors can be used in this mode, but is there something different in the construction of super capacitors which precludes this.If yes are diodes required to prevent reverse charging.

Comment: I smell an XY problem here.

Comment: @olinlathrop Are we sure supercaps behave the same as wet electrolytic capacitors in this respect? Otherwise, the duplicated answer (where supercaps are not mentioned at all, if I read that thread correctly - just skimmed it over) may not be actually a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Lorenzo.  This question may be ill-formed, but it is not a duplicate.  A 1F supercapacitor would take a million times longer to transfer a signal compared to a 1uF capacitor.  More filter than DC blocker.  Actually, interested in answer.